# Debug DLL failed to load, specified procedure could not be found error

Tags: visual-c++, dll, com, net-snmp

Need some hint for debugging DLL's. I have some legacy project, which I was able to build using `v141_xp` toolset on Windows 10.

It has a couple of its own dependencies like:

```
netsnmp.li
netsnmpagent.lib
netsnmpmibs.lib
netsnmptrapd.lib
netsnmphelpers.lib
Ws2_32.lib
snmpapi.lib
mgmtapi.lib
winmm.lib
```

And inherited:

```
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib
```

net-snmp-5.4.4 I build from source and installed in `C:\usr`.
Compilation and linking seemed to be successful.

But, trying to register resulting DLL showed that after all it was not that successful.

```
regsvr32 C:\Users\kqmw64\ctt_tools\toolsprojects\ToolsObjects\Debug\networkmanager.dll
```

Result in:
`The specified procedure could not be found` message.

I have checked export table, using http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

```
DllRegisterServer   0x6416c8c0  0x0006c8c0  3 (0x3) networkmanager.dll  C:\Users\kqmw64\ctt_tools\toolsprojects\ToolsObjects\Debug\networkmanager.dll   Exported Function
```

Added `MessageBox(0, "Dll Register Server", "caption", MB_OK);` to it, but obviously message box do not appear.

Would much appreciate some hint's how to approach this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the message comes from regsvr32? When I try regsvr32 on an invalid dll, it tells me "The module "Blabla.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "Blabla.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.". Maybe your module does things in its DllRegisterServer code?

Comment: Google "windows show loader snaps" to find web pages that tell you how to troubleshoot this error.

Comment: @SimonMourier In my case entry-point should be present from what I see in dll_export_viewer. But, I believe the process did not reach the point when this method is actually called. It is probably failed during loading. Something should be wrong in dll, or maybe unresolved dependency

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, seems like what I was looking for